# JQuery Internet Explorer and ajaxstop

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {loading.show()});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {loading.hide()});
```

How to invoke an event ajaxStop in Internet Explorer? ajaxStart works without problem

Answer (score 3):

You want `ajaxComplete`

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {loading.hide()});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/