# Internet Explorer and ajaxStart/ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When I send a jQuery, I want to display a loading gif via `ajaxStart()`. When finished, the gif should disappear by using `ajaxStop()`.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart( function () {
 $('#info').show();

}).ajaxStop( function () {
 $('#info').hide();
});
```

It works fine on Firefox, but not in IE (I'm using version 8). It seems that IE executes the `ajaxStart()` at the end of the query and right after that it executes the `ajaxStop()`. If I comment out the `$('#info').hide();` part, I see the gif after I get my data.

I can get around it by setting `async=true`, but I don't want to do that. Is there another way?

I read some articles indicating that lots of people have this problem but I couldn't find an answer.

**EDIT:**

I recognized that `ajaxStart` is executed correctly, but the request causes the browser to freeze till i get a response. This happens so fast that the loading gif cannot be shown. Tried it with an `alert()` after the `ajaxStart` and the gif shows up. After that the `alert` pops up and then the request is sent which causes the browser and gif to freeze.

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try use the `display` property to show/hide your DIV.

**HTML**

```
<div id="loading">&nbsp;</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#loading {
    display: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6) 
            url(../img/loading.gif) 
            50% 50% 
            no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $('#loading').css('display', 'block')
    },
    ajaxStop: function() {
        $('#loading').css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. The loading div shows in firefox but don't show in ie8 and ie9. What I did is I just added a setTimeout interval and its works.

First check if the browser is IE8 or IE9. In your html add this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en-us" class="ie ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en-us" class="ie ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html lang="en-us"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

If it is ie8 or ie9 add an interval, if not don't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ie8or9 = $('html').hasClass('ie8') || $('html').hasClass('ie9');
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#loading').show();
        }, ie8or9 ? 50 : 0);
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
        }, ie8or9 ? 100 : 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.  Not working for me in ie11 or Chrome.  Works fine with firefox as you found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to browse for answers to similar question on this site first, please.

[JQuery Internet Explorer and ajaxstop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800570/jquery-internet-explorer-and-ajaxstop)

You want ajaxComplete

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {loading.hide()});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work either. :-/ Also tried `ajaxSend()`.